# Get extra input which name is not in the model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model.

```
public class M 
{ 
    public int A { get; set; } 
    public int B { get; set; } 
}
```

And I have the following Razor view.

```
@model MyApp.Models.M
@using (Html.BEginForm("Create", "Test", new { id = ...}, FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.A)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.B)
    <input name="C">
}
```

The controller method,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Guid id, M m)
{
    // How to get C?
}
```

How to get the value of input C in the controller? (one solution may be creating an extra ViewModel and map it to model, is there any simpler method?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an additional method parameter called [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) formCollection and you can interrogate this formCollection for 'C'
e.g.

```
var yourValueForC = formCollection["C"]
```

Or you could just interrogate the request as follows

```
var yourValueForC = Request.Form["C"]
```

Comment: Is this correct? `public ActionResult Create(Guid id, M m, string C)`?

Comment: You could do that if you want too.